# properties of riemann integral real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need help with this problem please

Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and deﬁne the function $F(x) = \int 
f(t)dt$ from $a$ to $x$.

Show that $F$ satisﬁes a Lipschitz condition on $[a, b]$; that is, that there exists $M > 0$ such that for every
$x, y ∈ [a, b]$,

$|F(y) − F(x)| ≤ M|y − x|$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded: there is $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.  (See for instance Proposition 8.6 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf)).  Therefore for any $a \leq x < y \leq b$,

$|F(y) - F(x)| = |\int_x^y f| \leq (y-x) M$,

and thus $F$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $M$.  In the second inequality we used: if $m(x) \leq f(x) \leq M(x)$ are integrable functions on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b m \leq \int_a^b f \leq \int_a^b M$; together with the known integral of a constant function.  Careful derivations of these properties can be found e.g. in Chapter 8 of [loc. cit.](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).